# unable to get data using rest call with python

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, http-status-code-401

I am trying to make a rest call to put data from a remote site as follows:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
url = 'https://<private_site>:8021/rest/management/reports/create/jvm?type=XML&format=XML+Export&source=live:app1&filter=tf:CustomTimeframe?1533008450802:1533019250802'
try:
    r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'passwd'))
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  # This is the correct syntax
    print e
    sys.exit(1)
```

I can pull the url in the browser with no problem but when I try to get it with python, I get 401 error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your user/password combination is wrong.

401 Unauthorized

https://httpstatuses.com